# Storing new values from a while loop?? C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, increment

im not sure if someone asked this question before i couldn't find it in the search,

im using a normal while loop that generates a series of numbers and i want to store all these numbers as an int variable for each, here is my code so far

```
int numvalue = 30;
    while (numvalue<100){
        numvalue= numvalue + 10;
        cout << numvalue<< endl;
    }
```

Output:
40
50
60
70
80
90
100

so i need to store each output as an int variable and assign the names automatically , how should i go about this?

Comment: _"so i need to store each output as an int variable and assign the names automatically"_ [Can you please elaborate about this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26827870/edit)? I don't get it.

Comment: I think you want to make an array of integers and store into those.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define a 100 different variables? Are you familiar with the concept of arrays?

Comment: Yes, your question already has been asked here.

Comment: ah, yeah it is not 100 different variables, its the condition :/
problem solved by storing the output into a vector thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are statically defined so you cannot create names for them from the code in the for loop.

But you can make lists of values. In your case using the std::vector is probably the best choice:

```
#include <vector>
int value = 30;
std::vector<int> values;
while (numvalue<100){
    numvalue= numvalue + 10;
    values.push_back(numvalue);
    cout << numvalue<< endl;
}
```

So after the loop values will contain 7 values. values[0] will be 40, values[1] will be 50, etc.

Comment: Thanks Eelke! my problem is fixed now :)